# What is this PHP shortcode means? is_array($data) OR $data = (array) $data

Tags: php

What is this PHP code means ?

```
is_array($data) OR $data = (array) $data
```

I see this code on PyroCMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OR` is a short-circuit operator. If the left side is `true`, the right side will not be evaluated. It basically says "if `$data` is not an array, cast it to an array".

Note that this is rather redundant and could be abbreviated to:

```
$data = (array)$data;
```

This has the same effect. If it already is an array, casting to an array will do nothing, otherwise it will cast to an array.

Comment: It also ensures that the array $data exists (as does your version, but I feel it is worth mentioning).

Comment: @vascowhite Yes, but it's the wrong way to ensure that, since PHP will throw two notices if the variables *doesn't* exist.

Comment: thanks for mentioning "short circuit" keyword. that is very helpful. I really don't know that it can be done on PHP

Comment: @deceze definately the wrong way, your code is correct, I just thought it should be pointed out for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

It tests if $data is an array, and casts it to one if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It is equal to:

```
if (!is_array($data)) $data = (array) $data
```

Answer (score 0):

That code type casts $data to an array, if it's not an array.

More information on type casting - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 0):

It's a (terrible in my opinion) hackish way of writing:

```
if(!is_array($data)) {
    $data = (array) $data;
}
```

Which is basically forcing the $data variable to be an array.

Don't write code like this.  It's hard to process (mentally), and doesn't save any time.  :-)